# How do I set a generic type inside a generic class

Tags: c#, generics, parameters

I have a few classes

```
class Parameters{..}
class CalculationParameters : Parameters{..}
class CalculatorParameters<T> : Parameters where T:CalculationParameters{..}

class FourierTransformParameters : CalculationParameters
{
    public double FourierTransformCoefficient{ get; set; }
}

class Calculation{..}
class FourierTransform : Calculation{..}

class Calculator<T> where T:Calculation
{
    public CalculatorParameters<?> Parameters{ get; private set; }

    public Calculator(T calculation,int p1)
    {
        Parameters = new CalculatorParameters<?>(calculation.Parameters,p1);
    }
}
```

In place of the questionmark, I would like to do something like T.TRelatedCalculationParameters,
because at the time of construction, I know what T is and the questionmark type is fully defined by T. This way I could call:

```
var ft         = new FourierTransform()
var calculator = new Calculator<FourierTransform>(ft,3);
calculator.Parameters.FourierTransformCoefficient = 3;
```

I there a way to achieve this somehow?

Thanks, Jan

Comment: As there is no relation between a `Calculation` and its `Parameters`, you probably need two generic parameters on your `Calculator`-cöass. one for the `Calculation` and one for the `Parameters:

Answer (score 0):

Here you are constraining T to be type Calculation:

```
class Calculator<T> where T:Calculation
```

You then want to do:

class Calculator where T:Calculation
{
    public CalculatorParameters Parameters{ get; private set; }

In both cases T is contrained as type Calculation.

But you also have this, which contrains T to type CalculationParameters:

class CalculatorParameters : Parameters where T:CalculationParameters{..}

You cannot constrain T to both Calculation and CalculationParameters, as there is no inheritance relationship between them.